# How do Backbone models know which RESTful URL to use?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to wrap my mind around Backbone (as my recent flurry of questions indicate...). In particular I'm working through this project:

https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar
http://nodecellar.coenraets.org/#

I want to conceptually understand what happens when I click the "Save" button on a new Wine for example this one:

http://nodecellar.coenraets.org/#wines/506df6b6849a990200000001

I'm thinking it goes something like this:

1) The Backbone winedetails view catches the save button click as an event and launches the "Before Save" method. See below from /public/js/views/winedetails.js.

```
beforeSave: function () {
    var self = this;
    var check = this.model.validateAll();
    if (check.isValid === false) {
        utils.displayValidationErrors(check.messages);
        return false;
    }
    this.saveWine();
    return false;
},

saveWine: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log('before save');
    this.model.save(null, {
        success: function (model) {
            self.render();
            app.navigate('wines/' + model.id, false);
            utils.showAlert('Success!', 'Wine saved successfully', 'alert-success');
        },
        error: function () {
            utils.showAlert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying to delete this item', 'alert-error');
        }
    });
},
```

In that Save method (the 2nd method) there is a call to this.model.save. SOMEHOW that model save method MUST be making a PUT request to the '/wines' URL as evidenced in the server.js file (This is for a node.js server):

```
app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);
```

From there obviously it runs the addWine method which is defined in the routes/wines.js. What I don't understand is how the MODEL understands which URL to send the request to. I can't find anywhere that links the model.save method with the correct REST API. Does my question make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Wait I might have answered my own question. It must be this line in: /public/js/models/models.js

urlRoot: "/wines"

And then Backbone knows if you are doing an "New" model it must send a POST request. If you are doing an update it must append the :id to the URL and send a PUT request, etc. Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the `.save` method sends a POST for a new object, or a PUT for an existing one. Check out [this documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the model urlRoot : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

If you have specified the `urlRoot` on the model, it will use that. If the model is part of a collection, it will reference the [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) property on the collection.

When [saving](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save), Backbone will use PUT for an update and POST for a create. It determines which is should use based on the result of the [isNew](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew) function. This checks whether the model has an id property.